# Querystring containing `+` evaluating to space?

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string, urlencode, url-encoding

I have a parameter which I am passing as `querystring` to the page `URL`.Before passing the value as `querystring` I am encrypting the value. However the encrypted value sometimes contains the `+` in the `querystring`. I know it has special meaning in the `URL`. So I used `Server.UrlEncode(encryptedvalue)` to make it safe. But however when I get the `Querystring` only the `+` is getting evaluated before decoding the `URL`.

Here is code to Generate the query-string,

```
var result =  Server.UrlEncode(this.UserSecurity.Encrypt<string>(value));
```

after this value of querystring(result) is `+` becomes `%2b` as expected

```
querystringvalue = "R3oQCPn%2bNVV4P0aL0LAZEL6Og1%2bQ2vOJJDJCSTY6WXE%3d"
```

I have No control over `Encryption` method so I can not change in there.

So when I access at the redirected page I get,

1) When I don't use `UrlDecode` then `+` becomes

```
  querystringvalue = "R3oQCPn NVV4P0aL0LAZEL6Og1 Q2vOJJDJCSTY6WXE="
```

2) When I use the `UrlDecode` then still `+` becomes

```
  querystringvalue = "R3oQCPn NVV4P0aL0LAZEL6Og1 Q2vOJJDJCSTY6WXE="
```

3) When I see in watch window here is strange thing I see,
 [image]

As you can see there is `+` present in querystring but it getting resolved to .

So my question is,

1) Why the `%3d` not resolved to the `=` but the `%2b` resolved to `+` ?
2) And what Can I do to resolve this issue ? Because the `%2b` resolving to `+` and then to  giving me wrong decrypted value and some times format exception.

**UPDATE**
After generating the `result` I am directly attaching it to the URL without any further process as `"page.aspx?taskid="+result`

Comment: What are you doing with `result` before the next request?

Comment: Nothing, It gets directly attached to the URL as querystring.

Comment: Ok, can we see that code? And how the URL is returned to the client? (I.E. is this a redirect, embedded in the page as a link?)

Comment: You could use a modified Base64 encoding that doesn't use a `+` instead of `UrlEncode`.

Comment: @IanNewson It is embedded in page as link.

Comment: @CoderDennis Is there resource you know or sample would be great.

Comment: @CoderofCode `UrlTokenEncode` mentioned in the answer looks like it does exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to go out on a limb here and assume you are using BASE64 to encode the encrypted data, perhaps using `Convert.ToBase64String`.

Are you able to modify the `Encrypt` function?  If so, try encoding the bytes using `HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urltokenencode

To convert back to a `byte[]` use the symmetric `HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode` method.

[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urltokendecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urltokenencode)

This would allow you to safely pass the token in a URL.  Is this an option for you?

Comment: I am not using the `Convert.ToBase64String` to encrypt the data. Actualy the `Encryption` is done by the algorithm(I don't know which and I dont have access to the code I mentioned in question).

Comment: On second thought (When I started to read about it) I can convert my encrypted string  using `ENCODE` and `DECODE` using the `UrlTokenEncode`.

Comment: OK Great - In general the Server.UrlEncode() method doesn't catch as many characters as Uri.EscapeDataString().  I'm not totally sure why the implement things the way they did, but the later seems to handle just about every case.